# dxCircularGaugeOptions.valueIndicator.size property does not exist?

Tags: angular, devexpress

While working on a build process change I updated the `devextreme` and `devextreme-angular` modules to the latest version(from 16.2.6 to 17.2.4).

Now when I try to serve my application I get errors from my code about setting properties that do not exist such as:

```
this.dxCircularGaugeOptions.valueIndicator.size = 60;
error TS2339: Property 'size' does not exist on type '{ type?: string; }'
```

Now I guessed that maybe with the update of devextreme the API was updated too. A few minutes later I'm staring at the documentation for [valueIndicator](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Visualization_Widgets/dxCircularGauge/Configuration/valueIndicator/) and it seems that the valueIndicator object never had(even in older versions) a size property!

I am very confused how this used to work. Any ideas as to what I am doing incorrectly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many many hours later here's what I discovered:

- I found within the tsconfig file that my application was already
  referring to a copy of `dx.all.d.ts` (version: 16.2.6, prior to my
  update) using the "files" attribute.
- There is a file named `dx.all.legacy.d.ts` within
  `node_modules\devextreme\dist\ts` with a definition of an interface for
  `BaseValueIndicatorwhich` matches the code from my application.

Therefore in order to resolve my issue what I did was refer the `dx.all.legacy.d.ts` from within my tsconfig like:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
     ...
    },
    "files": [
        "../node_modules/devextreme/dist/ts/dx.all.legacy.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

I'm unsure if this is the best way to do this, but I hope it helps someone.